# Not able to zip folder in remote server

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm using Phpseclib to retrieve files from remote server. Everything works fine but when I tried to zip a folder to download. The zip file I created using code below remain empty. I'm out of idea how to make it works. Is there something wrong in my code?

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($host);

if (!$sftp->login($user, $password)) {
    exit('login failed');
}

$sftp->mkdir($zipfolder);
$sftp->put($zipfolder.'/'.$file, $sftp->get($file) );

$sftp->enablePTY();
$sftp->exec('cd '.$filepath.' && zip '.$zipfilename.' '.$zipfolder);
```

Comment: `sftp` itself does not support exec. You need `ssh` do to `exec()`.

Comment: @Jakuje - `SFTP`, in phpseclib, extends `SSH2`. As such it inherits all the same methods.

Comment: @neubert That is true, but if you don't have SSH access to that server, there is nothing you can do over SFTP protocol. It does not support execution of particular commands.

Comment: @kherP - it seems like you're basically moving `$file` from `~` to `~/$zipfolder`? if so it seems like `cp $file $zipfolder` might be a faster way to do it. Also, I'd try Adam's idea. Finally, I'm not sure what the point of `enablePTY()` is in your code segment..

Comment: Hi all, I tried Adam's idea and also yours. I was able to zip file but the zip file was not able to be extracted after download. Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ZIP directory you should write:

```
$sftp->exec('cd '.$filepath.' && zip -r '.$zipfilename.' '.$zipfolder);
```

Comment: I tried using $sftp->exec function again. Apparently, we can directly use SFTP to call SSH function. I was not able to zip the file using the command as zip command was not in my COPSSH. After adding the zip command, the above code worked just fine. Thanks Adam!